# how to open a sharepoint page by providing the user credentials explicitly

Tags: authentication

I want to open a native SharePoint 2010 page from my application (for example the Edit Properties page of a document) without the need to enter username/password, but instead to authenticate silently (prior or during the page request). is that possible?

In other words, i have a windows forms application, i enter a sharepoint document path and i click on a button, this will open up a windows form with a browser control that will navigate to the native "editform.aspx" sharepoint 2010 page for this document.Is there a way to authenticate the user without the need for him to enter his credentials?

Thanks,

Comment: is this a intranet? in a normal intranet scenario, credentials should automatically be provided to browser

Comment: yes, intranet, how to provide them to browser? (without the browser opening the login page?)

Answer (score 1):

if you specify the `DefaultNetworkCredentials` in your objects [CredentialCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

and use something similar to the below code:

```
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest w = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(u); 
    w.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

it should use the current users credentials automatically.

Answer (score 0):

On an intranet, so long as you are not using forms based authentication, it should automatically log a person in whether they are browsing, calling the web services or whatever. If it prompts, the URL probably needs to be added to the local intranet sites list in the browsers security settings.

Comment: exactly, but the idea here is to try to login using other credentials than the windows users (can i pass those to the browser silently via querystring or other ways?)

Comment: Gotcha. Yes it's possible. I wrote a WPF app that does this using the client object model.